# Java - Read from socket?

Tags: java, sockets, client

SO I just tried to read text from a socket, and I did the following:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class apples{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
        Socket client = null;
        PrintWriter output = null;
        BufferedReader in = null;
        try {
               client = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 2235);
               output = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), false);
               in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));

               while (true) {
                       System.out.println("Line: " + client.getOutputStream());
               }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        output.close();
        in.close();
        client.close();
    }
}
```

This prints out weird numbers and stuff like:

```
java.net.SocketOutputStream@316f673e
```

I'm not really sure of all the Java functions and things, so how would I make the output print out as text?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Write to a socket and read from it?

Comment: Well data is already being sent out, I just want to read from it. Sorry, I have no idea what I'm doing >.<

Answer (score 5, accepted):

look at:

```
while (true) {
     System.out.println("Line: " + client.getOutputStream());
}
```

getOutputSteam() returns an object that represents a stream. you can use this object to send data through the stream. here's an example:

```
BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(this._socket.getOutputStream());
out.write("hello");
out.flush();
```

this will send the message "hello" through the socket

to read the data, you will use the inputstream instead

let me just point out - this is a client that you are creating. You also need to create a server. Use java's ServerSocket class for creating a server

EDIT:
you want to write a client/server application in java.
you need to implement 2 processes: a client and a server.
the server will listen on some port (using ServerSocket).
the client will connect to that port, and send a message.

first object you need to understand is ServerSocket.
Server code:

```
ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(61616);    // this will open port 61616 for listening
Socket incomingSocket = s.accept();    // this will accept new connections
```

s.accept method is blocking - it waits for incoming connections, and goes to the next line only after a connection has been accepted. it creates a Socket object.
for this socket object you will set up an input stream and output stream (to send/receive data).

on the client:

```
Socket s = new Socket(serverIp, serverPort);
```

this will open a socket to the server. ip in your case will be "127.0.0.1" or "localhost" (local machine), and port will be 61616.

you will again, set up input/output stream, to send/receive messages

if you are connecting to a server that already exists, you only need to implement the client of course

you can find many examples online

Comment: Can you elaborate? I'm a noob- sorry for wasting your time. :3

Comment: He doesn't need to create a server. He is already connected to a server, otherwise he wouldn't get to print what he is printing. And you haven't answered the actual question. Downvote.

Answer (score 4):

You aren't reading *anything* with this code:

```
while (true) {
     System.out.println("Line: " + client.getOutputStream());
}
```

should be:

```
String line;
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
  System.out.println("Line: " + line); 
}
```

Comment: It says readLine() isn't a defined method for sockets O. o

Comment: Now it doesn't say anything O. o

Comment: I'm trying to connect to a server that already has output going- I know it runs on Java, and my connection goes through successfully. I just want to output the response text that the server gives T.T

Comment: @Ken if that doesn't read anything, nothing is being sent.

Comment: @Shahzeb: That is simply incorrect. The code I provided reads all the data until EOS. After that there *is* no more data. All that his while (true) does is to ignore EOS and loop forever.

Comment: @Shahzeb No. There is nothing to block *for* after EOS. `readLine()` returns `null` at EOS. EOS means that the connection has been closed by the peer. That's it. It is done. Finished. The end. Finis. Period. Reading a connection after you know it has been closed by the peer is always wrong. Reading an infinite number of EOS's is always wrong. It cannot have been intended.